# Make image disappear after X seconds (processing)

Tags: processing

I'm currently working on a project in which I want an image to pop up after 3 seconds. Once that image has popped up the user has to click on the image to make a "done" image pop up that will disappear automatically after 3 seconds.

I've got most of it working except for the disappearing part. Does anyone know how I can time the image to disappear after 3 seconds?

```java
PImage medic;
PImage medicD;

float time;
float startTime;

final int waitpopup = 3000;
final int DISPLAY_DURATION = 3000;

boolean showimage = true;
boolean showclock = true;
boolean showimagedone = true;
boolean hasClicked;

Clock clock;

void setup (){
size (1080, 1920);

 medic = loadImage("medic.png");
 medicD = loadImage("medicD.png");
 clock = new Clock(width /2, height /2);
 time = millis();
} 

void draw() {
 background (0);
 imageMode(CENTER);

 if (showclock) clock.display();

 if (showimage && millis() - time > waitpopup) {
   image(medic, width/2, height/2, 540, 540);
   } if (hasClicked == true) {
       showimage = false;
       image(medicD, width/2, height/2, 540, 540);
     } if (millis() > startTime + DISPLAY_DURATION) {
       showimagedone = false;
     }     
}

 void mousePressed() {
   hasClicked = true; 
   startTime = time;
 }
```

Comment: It looks like you're already setting `showimagedone` when the time has expired. But you never use that variable?

Comment: I see, how can I link that `showimagedone` and `showimage` to the `medic` and `medicD`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `millis()` function or the `frameCount` variable to check how much time has gone by, then do something after X seconds or after X frames.

You're already doing some of the work with the `showimagedone` variable, but you need to use that variable to conditionally draw your image.

I recommend [starting with a simpler example](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and getting that working. Here's one example:

```java
int clickedFrame;
boolean on = false;
int duration = 60;

void draw(){

  if(on){
    background(255);
    if(frameCount > clickedFrame + duration){
     on = false; 
    }
  }
  else{
   background(0); 
  }
}

void mousePressed(){
  clickedFrame = frameCount;
  on = true;
}
```

This code show a white background for one second whenever the user clicks the mouse. You need to do something similar with your images.

Related posts:

- [How to make a delay in processing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44572735/873165)
- [How can I draw only every x frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36505253/873165)
- [Removing element from ArrayList every 500 frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34907902/873165)
- [Timing based events in Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38145031/873165)
- [How to add +1 to variable every 10 seconds in Processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46271194/873165)
- [How to create something happen when time = x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43210363/873165)
- [making a “poke back” program in processing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40728044/873165)
- [Processing: How do i create an object every “x” time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36875493/873165)
- [Timer using frameRate and frame counter reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44666846/873165)
- [Adding delay in Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48085609/873165)

Please also consult [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/) for more information.

If you still can't get it working, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (not your full project!) in a new question and we'll go from there. Good luck.