# How can I slow down the random generation rate?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm just starting to learn P5 & JavaScript, and I've managed to create a canvas that has random patterns generated onto it. However, it seems like everything is being generated with the same framerate, which is making some of the objects/shapes appearing too fast. I tried changing the framerate to something slower, but it slows down the entire thing.

How can I just slow down the circles that are being randomly generated while keeping everything else at the same speed? Thank you!

```
// Variables for randomCircles function with squares occuring at random times
var spot = { 
  x: 1000,
  y: 500
}

var col= {
  r: 255,
  g: 0, 
  b: 0
}

var angle = 0;

var x = 10;

function setup() { 
  frameRate(12);
  background(45, 46, 45);
  createCanvas(600, 600);
}

function draw() {
  // Changing background color of canvas to a dark gray
  background(45, 46, 45);
  //background(255, 255, 255);
  targets();
  deadlyLaser();
  randomCircles();
  harmlessLasers();
  player();

// Four targets or "bars of gold" in the background
function targets() {
  push();
  var x = 0;
    while (x < width) {  
      fill(235, 200, 37); 
      stroke(235, 200, 37); 
      rect(x + 40, 300, 25, 25);
      x = x + 100
      pop();
    } 
}

// Rotating laser
function deadlyLaser(){
  push();
  translate(300, 300);
  rotate(-angle/15);
  strokeWeight(2);
  stroke(235, 40, 26);
  // Last parameter is opacity
  fill(235, 72, 59, 127);
  rect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  x = x + 1;
  angle = angle + 2;
  pop();
}

// Random circles appearing at random times with random color
function randomCircles(){
  push();
  noStroke();
  // Randomizing positions of circles within canvas
  spot.x = random(0, width);
  spot.y= random(0, height);
  // Giving circles opacity in lass parameter; full is 255
  fill(41, 227, 235, 200);
  ellipse(spot.x, spot.y, 50, 50);
  pop();
}

// Lasers going back and fourth, happening at spontaneous times, with a hint of random color   
function harmlessLasers(){  
  push();
  stroke(random(131, 152), random(219, 255), random(167, 195));
    for (var x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
      var y = randomGaussian(800, 1400);
      line(300, 300, x, y);
      pop();
    }
}

// Player line that appears when mouse is on canvas
function player(){
  push();
  stroke(0, 224, 64);
  strokeWeight(6);
  line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
  print(pmouseX + " - " + mouseX);
  pop();
 }
}
```

Comment: you can do anything with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to compare the time to a previous time and see if enough time has elapsed.

```
let timeLastUpdated = Date.now() // will hold the current date/time in milliseconds
```

The only thing you need now is a constant for the time elapsed before randomizing again, and then compare

```
const TIME_BETWEEN_RANDOMIZATIONS = 1000; // milliseconds between new randoms
```

then before you generate the new random numbers compare the time elapsed to the constant to see if we're ready to generate new numbers:

```
if (Date.now() - timeLastUpdated > TIME_BETWEEN_RANDOMIZATIONS) {
   // generate new random numbers
   spot.x = random(0, width);
   spot.y = random(0, height);

   // update the time
   timeLastUpdated = Date.now();
}
```

Comment: Please note that P5.js has its own timing functions. You'd probably want to use the `millis()` function instead.

Comment: Ah yes, very true; use `millis()` instead of Date.now()

Comment: Thank you both! Just double checking my understanding, so I would create the two variables (the timeLastUpdated and the constant) as global variables, then all the code in between the "noStroke();" and "pop();" (inclusive) would go in the if statement?

Comment: @Karen The idea you want to follow is keeping your drawing separate from your updating logic.  Each frame you will want to draw the circles. The circles will only be updated when the condition is true, which won't be true for every frame.  If you use an `update()` method to keep your logic, you'll find it's much easier to separate the code.

Comment: @RobBrander Ahh, that makes sense, thank you! I'll go ahead and give this another try :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `frameCount` variable or the `millis()` function to do timing-related logic. Here's a small example:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {

    // add a circle once per second
    if(frameCount % 60 == 0){
        ellipse(random(width), random(height), 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Related posts:

- [How to make a delay in processing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44572735/873165)
- [How can I draw only every x frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36505253/873165)
- [Removing element from ArrayList every 500 frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34907902/873165)
- [Timing based events in Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38145031/873165)
- [How to add +1 to variable every 10 seconds in Processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46271194/873165)
- [How to create something happen when time = x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43210363/873165)
- [making a “poke back” program in processing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40728044/873165)
- [Processing: How do i create an object every “x” time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36875493/873165)
- [Timer using frameRate and frame counter reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44666846/873165)
- [Adding delay in Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48085609/873165)
- [Make image disappear after X seconds (processing)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49783954/873165)

Please also consult [the P5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/) for more information.